# Wifi disconnecting frequently (16.04 - Ralink RT5392)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, ralink

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer. Everything works fine except the wifi which disconnects frequently (5-10 times per day): each time I have to disable wifi and enable it to make it works again.

There are other users of the same wifi network who are on different computers and OS (Mac, windows), and they have no problems.

Is there a way to fix the problem?

I have run the wireless info script, the result is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17635377/

Here is the output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2:

```
    05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless  Network Adapter [1814:5392]
    Subsystem: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:f053]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

And the output of sudo lshw -C network:

```
    *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlp5s0
   version: 00
   serial: 74:de:2b:39:5f:52
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-24-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.0.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:19 memory:fb100000-fb10ffff
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: enp6s0
   version: 06
   serial: 38:60:77:9f:a6:fa
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:25 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:da104000-da104fff memory:da100000-da103fff
```

Comment: There are quite a few similar posts with the same card and no solution. It could be a bug, that no one has reported yet, and thus has not been studied. I suggest you create a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux (full information about how to do that is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 6):

I ran into similar problems after a recent update to 16.04 with a Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61.

For me the solution was to edit default-wifi-powersave-on.conf with

`sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

and change wifi.powersave = 3 to wifi.powersave = 0

I've had no issues since. Perhaps this will work as well for you as it did for me.

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333291