# WIFI keeps disconecting Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04

Cable network works just fine, but wifi disconects randomly, y can't even load the gateway page for configurations when the connection fails.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Just a couple of days ago some very similar problem was asked and resolved.  Check this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789625/wifi-disconnecting-frequently-16-04-ralink-rt5392/836210

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I resolved it by restarting network-manager. Run this command in your terminal to restart network-manager :-

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Hope this helps !