# Ubuntu 16.10 Wifi Trouble - RT2561/RT61

Tags: networking, drivers, ralink, 16.10, pci

I've used Ubuntu before, but I'm still very new. I just installed 16.10 on a new computer yesterday, and the Wi-Fi has been considerably slower than my Windows laptop. I put the computer together mainly to play Dota 2, and I experience decent ping but constant 5%-10% packet loss while playing. Occasionally, after the computer has been left on for a while, the Wi-Fi connection will drop completely- I can still see networks in the drop down menu, including my home network, but my computer will not reconnect without a reboot. I've looked all over for a solution, but my inexperience has prevented me from getting anything to work. My Wi-Fi card is a Ralink RT2561/RT61, here's some info

The output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
 *-network                 
        description: Wireless interface
        product: RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
        vendor: Ralink corp.
        physical id: 6
        bus info: pci@0000:01:06.0
        logical name: wlp1s6
        version: 00
        serial: 00:0e:2e:de:df:c0
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt61pci driverversion=4.8.0-22-generic firmware=0.8 ip=192.168.1.107
 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:17 memory:dfef8000-dfefffff
```

Here is the output of `sudo iwconfig`:

```
 *-network                 
        description: Wireless interface
        product: RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
        vendor: Ralink corp.
        physical id: 6
        bus info: pci@0000:01:06.0
        logical name: wlp1s6
        version: 00
        serial: 00:0e:2e:de:df:c0
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt61pci driverversion=4.8.0-22-generic firmware=0.8 ip=192.168.1.107
 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:17 memory:dfef8000-dfefffff
```

I'm at a loss, I'm very bad at this. If any additional info is needed I can provide it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi disconnecting frequently (16.04 - Ralink RT5392)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/789625/wifi-disconnecting-frequently-16-04-ralink-rt5392)

Answer (score 5):

I have a RT2561/RT61 and I finally solved this problem by:

Edit this file as root:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Changing `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2`, which will disable powersave (as mentioned before, from [github](https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55))

And then restart the network manager as root:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

You don't need to reboot. You can now connect to your wifi device

---

(This answer is a compilation of previous answers, this method should be highlighted as **it saved me from buying hardware**)

Answer (score 1):

You must use 4.4.0 kernel (used as default in 16.04) then install from source the ralink/mediatek driver for linux "DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022".

After a reboot you wont lose packets anymore :).

You need kernel 4.4.0 because newer kernel 4.6+ had a change in API so the, very old, driver ralink not compile/work and without it you get packets loss.

In my rt2800usb.conf i setted also "options rt2800usb nohwcrypt=Y swenc=Y fwlps=N ips=N" and turned off wifi power management.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given to a similar problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/836210/609185) seems to have helped greatly but is not the accepted answer.

First, open a terminal and run the following command to edit the file.

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 0/g' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Finally, `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` (or reboot).

The command edits the file: `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to change: `wifi.powersave = 3` to this instead: `wifi.powersave = 0`

Comment: You should upvote the linked answer if it has helped you. I have placed a close request marking the question as a duplicate so that it links to the answer. However, because the answer was not accepted as the solution on the previous question, I went ahead and edited your answer to include the steps with a link to the original source as it is not proper to provide a "link only answer".

Comment: Also, I went ahead and used `sed` to edit the file instead of `gedit` because it is quicker and more impressive :).

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/g' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Should work better according to this from [github](https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55)

As it shows 0 = use default, 1 = ignore, 2 = disable, and 3 = enable