# Ubuntu 20.04LTS: Ralink RT2561/RT61 keeps deauthenticating

Tags: networking, 20.04, ralink

Recently backed up the home folder from a 16.04 LTS install, wiped the disk and did a fresh install of 20.04 LTS, and restored the home folder from the backup. Since then, wifi connects but is slow and regularly drops authentication.

I've tried reloading the [wireless kernel module](https://askubuntu.com/a/1308676/580023), changing the [wifi powersaving settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/878533/580023), and [deactivating the N-mode of the driver](https://superuser.com/a/912284/628079), with no results.

I think I might need to either recompile the wifi drivers or adjust the kernel version, but I'm not sure which, and I'd rather not touch the kernel if I don't have to. Can anyone offer any insight into which one is likely to be the issue?

**sudo lshw -C network:**

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 12
   serial: 00:1d:60:57:d3:e3
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:28 memory:fe9fc000-fe9fffff ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fe9c0000-fe9dffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:05:01.0
   logical name: wlp5s1
   version: 00
   serial: 00:18:f8:b0:fd:53
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt61pci driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=0.8 ip=192.168.0.112 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:febf8000-febfffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:3
   logical name: wlx0015af2398bc
   serial: 00:15:af:23:98:bc
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

**ifconfig -a:**

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:1d:60:57:d3:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8827  bytes 790555 (790.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8827  bytes 790555 (790.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp5s1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.112  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::3b66:3466:167d:f349  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:18:f8:b0:fd:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25701  bytes 20660841 (20.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23721  bytes 6775707 (6.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx0015af2398bc: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:15:af:23:98:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**sudo iwconfig:**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx0015af2398bc  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          
wlp5s1    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"00placeholder00"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 94:10:3E:A8:9C:4E   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:199  Invalid misc:3999   Missed beacon:0
```

**lspci:**

```
05:01.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
```

**dmesg:**

```
[ 2348.175565] wlp5s1: authenticate with a2:2b:b0:ea:23:7a
[ 2348.190043] wlp5s1: send auth to a2:2b:b0:ea:23:7a (try 1/3)
[ 2348.392544] wlp5s1: send auth to a2:2b:b0:ea:23:7a (try 2/3)
[ 2348.596457] wlp5s1: send auth to a2:2b:b0:ea:23:7a (try 3/3)
[ 2348.800346] wlp5s1: authentication with a2:2b:b0:ea:23:7a timed out
```

Comment: Was there only your personal data in that directory or may their have been some system data in it that could be the problem?

Comment: @David I copied the whole home directory, including hidden folders, so it's possible it could be affected by some system data. Any in particular that I should check?

Comment: Have you examined the logs on your wireless AP? Is it receiving the authentication attempts?

Comment: I am noticing a discrepancy in the width output of `sudo lshw -C network` .  The width of your ethernet interface is 64bits.  The width of the wireless interface is 32bit.  I think this could be contributing to your problem.  When I ran that same command all interfaces show 64bit.

Comment: **I think you don't have the ralink driver installed**

Comment: Try reinstalling the drivers of ralink using the github page that will definitely help.

Comment: @TBr Is that something I can change on the wireless interface end or the network settings end? I suspect the Ralink is old enough that 32bit is its limit.

Comment: @JamesS. As far as I can tell, yeah; I'll take another look just to be sure.

Comment: @AkshajSingla https://github.com/rhertzog/firmware-nonfree/tree/master/ralink ?

Comment: The only way I could see making a change from 32 bit to 64 bit is through a driver that is 64 bit.  Again it's just something I noticed but may or may not be contributing to your issue.

Comment: Here's a related question but it refers to ubuntu 16.10. https://askubuntu.com/questions/839479/ubuntu-16-10-wifi-trouble-rt2561-rt61  I'm not sure if anything there will help in your case but could be worth looking at anyway.

Comment: This may actually help, it's in regards to a similar issue with a different wireless card for 20.04.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230140/wifi-keeps-dropping-out-ubuntu-20-04-and-broadcom-wireless-adaptor?noredirect=1&lq=1